Magento 2 module for epago.pe [web-agoraweb-button]
There is payment gateway [https://docs.epago.pe/web-agoraweb-button] and they have provided a piece of javascript code to integrate their payment gateway with any platform but I don't know how to integrate this payment gateway in magento 2 application. I followed this blog [https://www.magedelight.com/resources/steps-to-create-custom-payment-method-in-magento-2/] to create a basic payment method and the method showing on my store checkout page. But how and where to integrate this payment gateway javascript code in magento 2 ? Any guidence or good blog post URL to achieve this is much appriciated.
